# Make bootstrap 5 dropdown menu fully visible in a scrollable modal body

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdown inside a fixed height and scrollable modal body. The height of dropdown menu exceeds the modal body. When dropdown is open, it will cause the body scroll. How can I make the dropdown menu fully visible?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leoliaolei/ck3h9uzf/24/)

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">
      Modal Title
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body bg-secondary" style="height:15rem; overflow-y:auto;">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      Modal body is fixed height and scrollable. Want to make dropdown menu fully visible.
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="p-3" style="width:10rem;height:12rem;">
          Dropdown Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

dropdown.addEventListener('shown.bs.dropdown', () => {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
    dropdownMenu.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth", 
      block: "end",
      inline: "nearest"
    });
  });
});
```